# multiple Inheritance in JS

Tags: javascript

There javascript class, if he can 'inherit' a few objects - that is, to know their   methods

```
var A = function  (a,c){};

var N = {  
     properties1: function(){};
};

var M1 = {
     properties2: function(){};
};
var M2 = {
     properties3: function(){};
};
```

How to do that would 'A' , knew (the heir) of 'N' and 'M1' , 'M2' ...'M10' ...  ?

```
A.prototype = N;
A.prototype = M1;
A.prototype = M2;
```

It does not work :(
How to implement such an event structure in javascript

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not supported in JS.

Comment: Can it be like that circumvent or emulate?If you need a structure described above ?

Comment: Take a look at [mixins](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/).

Comment: I wonder why you even expect assigning to `A.prototyep` multiple times to work. If I have this code: `var a = 1; a = 2; a = 3;`, then in the end, `a` will have the value `3`, not `1, 2, 3` (somehow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has `prototypical` model/inheritance. Please use it and avoid writing `Java/C++` in Javascript. **It's a different model**.

**EDIT:**

In my opinnion if you need such a thing - **you're doing it wrong** :). And I very much recommend to read this [SO answer about prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: A.prototype = N; A.prototype = M1     === replaced by ===   A.prototype.properties1 = N.properties1; A.prototype.properties2 = M1.properties2